# document.getElementsByTagName returning undefined on placing the script after body

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this is a frequently asked question.
I have tried all the methods like using onload() for body tag,
placing the script after the DOM elements and using self invoking function.
Yet I get that my element is undefined.

P.S: `document.getElementsByTagName('')` replaced with `document.getElementById('')` works fine. Why is that? Please explain both of my doubts. Here is my simple code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="loadHandler()">
  <p>Drag me!</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadHandler() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('p').setAttribute('draggable', true);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess it's because 'getElementsByTagName' is returning an array, where getElementById is just returning a single element.

I was too slow :D

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` return `HTMLCollection`, you can access its element using array like notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` (as the name suggests) returns an array of elements. If you want the first one, take the first one.

```css
.highlight{ color: red}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="loadHandler()">
  <p>Drag me!</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadHandler() {
      var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
      elem.setAttribute('draggable',true)
      elem.classList.add('highlight');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As for why dragging is not working, perhaps the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable) might shed some light

> By default, only text selections, images, and links can be dragged. For all others elements, the event ondragstart must be set for the drag and drop mechanism to work, as shown in this [comprehensive example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations).

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns array of results, not just a single result like getElementById. Try to use getElementsByTagName('p')[0].

Comment: What do you mean by 'It doesn't help'? I've checked by myself and that gets rid of this error.